# Using class from package in main

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to swift , I am using Xcode and I just created 2 packages in my project - Player and Game with classes Player.swift and Game.swift and outside the packages and inside the project i have a main.swift. In the main.swift I am doing the following

```
import Foundation
import Player
let myPlayer = Player()
```

But Xcode complains - No such module 'Player' . Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Yes , when I put import Player , then on that line it gives me No such module 'Player'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you forgot a key step. (I know because I always forget it too.)

After creating a package, you must *add* the package's library to your app target. Until you do that, the app target cannot see the package module.

[image]

Comment: @Frankenstein No. Weird, eh? When you download the package by adding it as a dependency, then you have an option to check a checkbox that does this for you. But not when you create a package. Even if you remember to add the package to a project, Xcode does not get the idea that you might be adding the package to this project because you'd like to _use_ the package _in_ the project.

Comment: Well that's the part about the _main.swift_. You have to edit the app target. But if you created a command line tool by mistake, you have no app target. But that's a different issue, as I said.

Comment: Yeah indeed I have created command line tool , my project will work with the command line.What option's do I have to achieve this?

Comment: Ok you can still do it. Just edit the target exactly as you would for a normal app: click on the project, click on the target, see Frameworks and Libraries, click Plus and import the package library.